# For all sets $A, B$ and $C$, if $C⊆(B-A)$, then $A∩C=∅$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> I am trying to proof the question for all sets $A, B$ and $C$, if $C⊆(B-A)$,  then  $A∩C=∅$.

Here is my thoughts. Assuming that $A∩C$ is not $∅$. Then I can get $x∈A$ and $x∈C$.From the question, since $C⊆(B-A)$, I get $x∈B$ and $x∈A^c$. $x$ is in both $A$ and $A^c$, therefore this is the contradiction.

Would appreciate your help to get the proper and correct way to prove this question.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct! Just another (equivalent) way to write this: Since $B-A=B\cap A^c$, you have that $$A\cap C\subseteq A\cap(B\cap A^c)=A\cap A^c\cap B=\emptyset\cap B=\emptyset$$

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, I type the question wrongly.

Comment: @user292965 Yes, this answer corresponds to the edited question.

Comment: @user292965 I edited my answer to include that your solution (which I had not seen in my first reading of the OP) is perfectly fine!

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks! Is the solution just as short as what you wrote? I mean do I need to state by contradiction etc..... Thanks!

Comment: @user292965 Yes, your contradiction is really short and nice too. Actually we use the same argument, that $B-A \subseteq A^c$. So, I would only add in your answer the sentence: "$... C\subseteq B-A$ but $B-A=B\cap A^c\subseteq A^c$, so I get $x\in B$ and $x\in A^c$..." and leave the rest as it is.

Answer (score 2):

$C \subseteq B\setminus A$ means that every element of $C$ is contained by $B$ but not by $A$. Hence $A\cap C$ is empty.